# Perl: How to find and modify multiple expressions in a single string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that contains many lines like the following:

```
guide_points { {3230.779 3075.482} {3230.779 2952.239} {3253.180 2952.239}
```

Each pair of values are X and Y coordinates. For each line in the file, I want to find every Y value and add a certain value (lets say 205.632) and print that new line. The Y value will always precede a } without any space. I need the new string to look just like the original except each Y value should be increased by 205.632.

I am trying this command:

```
$line =~ s/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)\}\K/$1 + 205.632/ge
```

But this gives me the following:

```
guide_points { {3230.779 3075.482}3281.114 {3230.779 2952.239}3157.871 {3253.180 2952.239}3157.871 }
```

The \K is keeping the original Y value and the }.  I want the new Y value followed by }, like this:

```
guide_points { {3230.779 3281.114} {3230.779 3157.871} {3253.180 3157.871} }
```

Appreciate any help in fixing my search/replace command.

Comment: `$line =~ s/(\d+\.\d+)}/$1+205.632 . '}'/ge;`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$line =~ s/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)\}/($1 + 205.632) . "}"/ge;
```

Replaces the number followed by `}` with the number increased by 205.632 and appends a `}` to that number since without the `\K` the bracket is removed also.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like following sample code can be utilized

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $inc_y = 205.632;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    say '-' x 80;
    say 'IN:  ' . $_;
    s/{(\d+\.\d+) (\d+\.\d+)}/"{$1 " . ($2+$inc_y) . '}'/ge;
    say 'OUT: ' . $_;
}


__DATA__
guide_points { {3230.779 3075.482} {3230.779 2952.239} {3253.180 2952.239}
guide_points { {3231.779 3076.482} {3231.779 2953.239} {3254.180 2953.239}
```

Output

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IN:  guide_points { {3230.779 3075.482} {3230.779 2952.239} {3253.180 2952.239}
OUT: guide_points { {3230.779 3281.114} {3230.779 3157.871} {3253.180 3157.871}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IN:  guide_points { {3231.779 3076.482} {3231.779 2953.239} {3254.180 2953.239}
OUT: guide_points { {3231.779 3282.114} {3231.779 3158.871} {3254.180 3158.871}
```